# Adjust default height JQTE

Tags: jquery, css, jqte

How can I change the default height of a JQTE editor?
I've tried:

```
$("textarea").jqte({
height:"400px"
});
```

The document does not say anything about this.

Answer (score 4):

You should try changing the min-height value for jqte_editor in jqte stylesheet:

```
 /* editor area */
.jqte_editor, .jqte_source {
    min-height:300px;
}
```

Comment: You will need to increase the specificity of your selector if the JQTE CSS is included after your styling (eg. `body .jqte_editor, body .jqte_source` or even `.jqte_editor.jqte_editor, .jqte_source.jqte_source`)

Answer (score 2):

To lock editors height so a scrollbar appears instead of the editor expanding, you need to set `.jqte_editor` `height` or `min-height`. You also need to set `max-height`.

**What happends next is a jqte bug:**

- Select a text and add bold/italic or some other formatting
- Remove the formatting
- The selected text suddenly inherits the
  `.jqte_editor` height values and pushes every element (text) beneath further down

**Fix (jqte version 1.4.0)**

Open the javascript file `jquery-te-1.4.0.js`.

Search and find `function affectStyleAround(element,style)`

Replace:

```
if(selectedTag && style==false)
{
    // apply to the selected node with parent tag's styles
    if(selectedTag.parent().is("[style]"))
        selectedTag.attr("style",selectedTag.parent().attr("style"));

    // apply to child tags with parent tag's styles
    if(selectedTag.is("[style]"))
        selectedTag.find("*").attr("style",selectedTag.attr("style"));
}
```

With this:

```
if(selectedTag && style==false)
{
    // apply to the selected node with parent tag's styles
    if(selectedTag.parent().is("[style]") && !selectedTag.parent().is(".jqte_editor"))
        selectedTag.attr("style",selectedTag.parent().attr("style"));

    // apply to child tags with parent tag's styles
    if(selectedTag.is("[style]") && !selectedTag.parent().is(".jqte_editor"))
        selectedTag.find("*").attr("style",selectedTag.attr("style"));
}
```

Notice the added code:

```
 && !selectedTag.parent().is(".jqte_editor")
```

Good luck!

Comment: I think the second part should be "if(selectedTag.is("[style]") && !selectedTag.is(".jqte_editor"))" (drop the .parent() bit)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.jqte_editor').css({ height: '250px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't provide an option, but you can do this:

```
$("textarea").css('min-height','400px').jqte();
```

This will automatically set the height to minimum of `400px`

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late but i was looking for a solution too without changing the original css as some pages i want it default and some i want it custom size. simple set inline css after the plugin js. something like this.

```
$('.te_editor').jqte({
});

<style>
.jqte_editor{height:350px;max-height:500px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Your selector on JS are wrong, it should be `.jqte_editor`, the same as CSS. Also, always put the styles on the header of the document, before the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the patch suggested by VKS (with a slight mod, see my comment on his answer).

I use something like this to try to calculate the height of the edit area taking the original textarea "rows" attribute (without VKS's patch this causes horrible problems):

```
var $areas = $("textarea.html-editor");
$areas.each(function (index, textarea) {
    var $area = $(textarea);
    $area.jqte();
    var $editor = $area.closest(".jqte").find(".jqte_editor");
    var height = ($area.attr("rows") * 25 / 15) + "em";
    $editor.css({ "min-height": height, "max-height": height });
});
```

(that calculation rows*25/15 is just what happens to work for me in my particular case using "em"s - you will want to use your own calculation, there are many solutions e.g. measure "px" height of span with desired font etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is THE solution. Go to the **non-min version** to better see this solution. I just added a tiny amount of code to make it possible to pass in "height" as a startup option that gets perfectly inserted to control the height of the component.

On line 215 of version 1.4.0, add this modification:

```
<div class="'+vars.css+"_editor"+'" style="height:'+vars.height+';"></div>
```

You're adding the following code:

```
style="height:'+vars.height+';"
```

Then pass in {height:'500px'} into your code like so:

```
$(".myCustomTextField").jqte({'height': '500px'});
```

DONE!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the height of a specific textarea, i sugest you to put your text area inside a div like this

```
<div class="custom-jqte">
  <textarea id="yourtextarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

then, put this on a css file

```
.custom-jqte .jqte_editor {
   height: 400px;
}
```

With this method, you avoid changing the jquery-te stylesheet